# Checkbox checked flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have a problem with a checkbox in a form

```
<form id="form" action="/findPkgInstalled" role="form" method = "POST">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
      <input type="text" name="pkgSearch" placeholder="Ricerca applicazione non installate..">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6><input type="checkbox" name="filterName" checked>Filtra per nome</h6>
</form>
```

while in Python I have:

```
@app.route('/findPkgInstalled', methods=['POST'])
def findPkgInstalled():
    error = None
    pkg = request.form['pkgSearch']
    if not pkg:
        flash(u'Operazione errata, impossibile ricercare stringa vuota','warning')
        return redirect(url_for('listInstalled'))
    else:
        if request.form['filterName'] is 'on':
            appFound = aptsearch(pkg,True)
            return render_template('find-pkg-not-installed.html', appFound = appFound)
        else:
            appFound = aptsearch(pkg,False)
            return render_template('find-pkg-not-installed.html', appFound = appFound)
    return redirect(url_for('listInstalled'))
    box = request.form['filterName']
```

but this does not work. The error reported is 400 Bad Request. How can I do? Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you're trying to fetch an object from your post request using incorrect key. For example if you uncheck `filterName` checkbox - this will cause this error:

```
request.form['filterName']
```

My advises:

0) Always check your post body to know what keys you can use to retrieve values from this body.

1) Use

```
request.form.get('filterName')
```

instead of

```
request.form['filterName']
```

because `.get()` returns `None` is there is no such key instead of throwing an exception inside flask that leads to 400 error

2) Use

```
request.form.get('filterName') == 'on'
```

instead of

```
request.form['filterName'] is 'on'
```

because `is` returns True if two variables point to the same object in memory. I'm not sure if you already have 'on' object in process memory

Comment: Thanks! I check if request.form.get('filterName') is None or not... it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add value, to your checkboxes.
if its checked, you get that value, else you get None.

Ive solved my problem with

```
    if request.form.get("check") == None:
        value = 0
    else:
        value = 1
```

and also it is ok if i dont use the else statement if only

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">
```